# Loading a string containing a list of JSON objects

Tags: python, json

I have string that has a list of JSON objects in it. How can I access each JSON obj? json.loads() does not work since the string is a list of objects and does not have the proper format.

Here is the format of the string I have:

```
myString = '[{"name": "John", "ID": "1"}, {"name": "Jane", "ID": "2"}]'
```

UPDATE:

There is a particular line in the input file that seems to generate the below error when I try to read it (I have isolated that line: https://www.dropbox.com/s/8i9aj64i5r8dmgp/line.00?dl=0):

```
            for line in inFile:

            Traceback (most recent call last):
              File "../filterBios.py", line 29, in <module>
                line = json.loads(line);
              File "/N/soft/rhel6/python/2.7.3/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 326, in loads
                return _default_decoder.decode(s)
              File "/N/soft/rhel6/python/2.7.3/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 366, in decode
                obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
              File "/N/soft/rhel6/python/2.7.3/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 382, in raw_decode
                obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
            ValueError: Unterminated string starting at: line 1 column 84647 (char 84647)
```

I cannot figure out what is causing the issue.

Comment: What exactly happens when you call json.loads on that string?

Comment: That appears to be a perfectly valid JSON string; an array of objects is fine. Please give a [mcve] that actually recreates the problem.

Comment: Your string is valid and I was able to use `json.loads()` with no problems.

Comment: `json.loads(myString)` creates a list of JSON objects you require. You can also index them.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out! The input text file had a NEL character and it turns out that:
    codec.open() 
cannot handle that. Use instead:
    io.open() 
and the " ValueError: Unterminated string" error will go away!

Answer (score -1):

`json.loads()` seems to work fine with the string you have provided. A `list` of JSON objects are created from the string which can be easily accessed by indexing.

```
In []: a = json.loads(myString)

In []: a
Out[]: [{'ID': '1', 'name': 'John'}, {'ID': '2', 'name': 'Jane'}]

In []: type(a)
Out[]: list

In []: len(a)
Out[]: 2

In []: a[0]
Out[]: {'ID': '1', 'name': 'John'}

In []: type(a[0])
Out[]: dict
```

Comment: @AG100 That's a totally separate issue. You can use a context manager to read from a file and iterate the lines. This method will work as long as you can deduce `myString` as a string type object.